# Storing spreadsheets in a database

Tags: sql, database

I am attempting to create a relational database to hold data from experiments which return csv files filled with data. This would allow me to search up an experiment I want based on date, author, experimental values etc.

However, I am not sure how to implement the relational database with the experiments which each generate seperate csv files.

Would it be possible to have a csv file as a column of the database or would it just be better to hold the name of the file?

Comment: you can do either. Databases can store files. Depending on the DBMS it is usually reasonably efficient in a modern database to store the files inside, but conventional wisdom is to store just the file path and store the file itself elsewhere on disk. Modern DBMSs will usually implement a file column as file-based storage anyway though so it potentially makes little difference.

Comment: I wouldn't store the file in a single column or a reference to the file. I would create tables that have the same structure as the files and the import those lines from the CSV into rows of the table.

Comment: The CSV file is a table filled with data generated from sensors. Each time the sensors capture something a new row is generated in the CSV with a timestamp. I'm not sure what you mean. Wouldn't that just recreate the CSV file as you're taking the rows out and putting them back in to a table with the same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

In general, databases have the ability to store large objects (usually, "BLOB"s -- binary large objects).

Whether this meets your needs depends on several factors.  I would say that the first is accessibility to the data.  Storing the strings in the database has some advantages:

- Anyone with access to the database has access to the data.
- To repeat: Users do not need separate user access to a file system.
- The same API can be used for the metadata and for the underlying data.
- You have more controls over the contents -- the underlying file cannot be deleted without deleting the row in the database, for instance.
- The data is automatically included in backups and restores.

Of course, there are downsides as well, some of which are related to the above:

- With a separate file, it is simpler to update the file, if that is necessary.
- Storing the data in a database imposes overheads (although you might be able to get around this by compressing the data).
- If the application is already file-based and you are added a database component, then changing the application to support the database could be cumbersome.

I'm sure these lists are not complete.  The point is that there is no "right" answer.  It depends on your needs.